# Symmetric bilinear forms, quadratic forms and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, solution-verification, bilinear-form

[image]

I have computed B=$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 4 & -1 \\
4 & 2 & 3 \\
-1 & 3 & 1 \end{array} \right) $

Is this correct? If so, even though I may have achieved the correct answer, can you explain the general method for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

A quadratic form on $K^3$ is a polynomial $Q\in K[x,y,z]$ of the form
$$
Q(x,y,z)=a\, x^2+b\,y^2+c\,z^2+d\,xy+e\,xz+f\,yz
$$
where $a,b,c,d,e,f\in K$. The matrix representing $Q$ is the matrix $B$ satisfying
$$
Q(x,y,z)=
\begin{bmatrix}
x&y&z
\end{bmatrix}
B
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Can you unravel these equations and check your answer?

Comment: I believe my matrix corresponds to $8xy+6yz-2xz+2y^2+z^2$, so it's not correct!

Comment: Can I assume that B is a symmetric matrix?

Comment: You can *prove* that $B$ has to be symmetric!

Answer (score 0):

You have to divide by two (when in characteristic$\;\neq2\;$) each coefficient of the mixed variables $\;xy\,,\,\,xz\,,\,\,yz\;$ , but you *multiplied them* by two! It should be

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&-1\\
1&2&0\\-1&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Didn't I, @user43290 ? It follows from the fact that $$Q(x,y,z)=(x\;y\;z)A\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=u^tAu$$ for any vector $\;u\;$ . and with $\;A\;$ the matrix of the quadratic form.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to divide by 2, otherwise, I follow your reasoning!